# How to extract concatenated symbols and rules from a hierarchy imported from a JSON file

Tags: list-manipulation

I'd like to do the following:

A sample JSON file.

```
{
    "L1N1": {
        "L2N1": "L2N1_Value_Cat",
        "L2N2": "L2N2_Value_Dog"
    },
    "L1N2": [
        {
            "L2N1": "L2N1_Value_Fish",
            "L2N2": "L2N2_Value_Mouse"
        },
        {
            "L2N1": "L2N1_Value_Bird",
            "L2N2": "L2N2_Value_Chimp"
        }
    ]
}

Import["Sample.json"]
```

Generate symbols by concatenating the node names and array indexes.

```
symbols = { Symbol["L1N1\[UnderBracket]L2N1"], 
   Symbol["L1N1\[UnderBracket]L2N2"], 
   Symbol["L1N2\[UnderBracket]1\[FilledSmallSquare]L2N1"], 
   Symbol["L1N2\[UnderBracket]1\[FilledSmallSquare]L2N2"], 
   Symbol["L1N2\[UnderBracket]2\[FilledSmallSquare]L2N1"], 
   Symbol["L1N2\[UnderBracket]2\[FilledSmallSquare]L2N2"]} // Column
```

And generate rules:

```
rules = {  L1N1\[UnderBracket]L2N1 -> "L2N1_Value_Cat",
   L1N1\[UnderBracket]L2N2 -> "L2N2_Value_Dog",
   L1N2\[UnderBracket]1\[FilledSmallSquare]L2N1 -> "L2N1_Value_Fish",
   L1N2\[UnderBracket]1\[FilledSmallSquare]L2N2 -> "L2N2_Value_Mouse",
   L1N2\[UnderBracket]2\[FilledSmallSquare]L2N1 -> "L2N1_Value_Bird",
   L1N2\[UnderBracket]2\[FilledSmallSquare]L2N2 -> 
    "L2N2_Value_Chimp" } // Column
```

This is my first foray into using Mathematica after a 25-year hiatus. So I'm essentially a newbie.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to achieve this is to use [`MapIndexed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapIndexed.html) to get the "path" of each element:

```
data = Import["Sample.json", "RawJSON"];

First@Last@Reap[             (* Reap/Sow to get a flat structure *)
  MapIndexed[                (* MapIndexed[…, …, -1] to map over all entries *)
    Sow[
      StringDrop[                (* Remove the separator at the end *)
        StringJoin @@ (          (* join the parts of the path *)
          #2 /. {                (* transform the elements of the path *)
            Key[s_] :> s <> "⎵", (* string keys (i.e. properties of objects) get a ⎵ *)
            i_Integer :> ToString@i <> "◼" (* array indices get a ◼ *)
            }
          ),
        -1
        ] -> #
      ] &,
    data,
    {-1}
    ]
  ]
(* {"L1N1⎵L2N1" -> "L2N1_Value_Cat", 
 "L1N1⎵L2N2" -> "L2N2_Value_Dog", 
 "L1N2⎵1◼L2N1" -> "L2N1_Value_Fish", 
 "L1N2⎵1◼L2N2" -> "L2N2_Value_Mouse",
  "L1N2⎵2◼L2N1" -> "L2N1_Value_Bird",
  "L1N2⎵2◼L2N2" -> 
  "L2N2_Value_Chimp"} *)
```

Importing as `"RawJSON"` directly gives us the objects as `Association`, rather than list of rules (thanks @CarlWoll!). After that, the code is just replacing the elements of the position specification accordingly and joins everything using `StringJoin`.

---

A less terse but more readable way (@Kuba):

```
foo[value_, {Key[a_], Key[b_]}] := 
 StringTemplate["``⎵``"][a, b] -> value
foo[value_, {Key[a_], n_Integer, Key[b_]}] := 
 StringTemplate["``⎵``◼``"][a, n, b] -> value

First @ Last @ Reap @ MapIndexed[
  Sow @* foo,
  data,
  {-1}
] // Column
```

Comment: You could also use `Import["Sample.json", "RawJSON"]` and avoid the need for ``GeneralUtilities`ToAssociations``.

Comment: @CarlWoll Thanks, I knew I used something like that in the past - the sad thing is, I even had the documentation of "RawJSON" open, I looked at it and decided "no, that's not what I'm looking for". I guess sometimes I'm just blind ;)

Comment: Hope you don't mind the edit, my solution's essence (MapIndexed) was the same as yours so I decided it fits here rather than deserves a separate answer.

Comment: Very helpful, thanks!

Comment: @Kuba, it seems your approach doesn't generalize to arbitrary tree depth whereas the code provided by Carl does generalize.

Comment: Oops! ...I mean provided by Lukas. Credit where credit is due.